# Individual Pages are loading halfway down

Tags: jquery, javascript, front-end, performance

folks. I'm working on an event booking site for a client, and for some reason, the event pages keep loading halfway down, but I can't figure out why. I'm not seeing any code that's causing it.

I've never had this issue before on any site at all. Even when I clear my browser cache, try Chrome and Safari (mobile and desktop), the issue persists.

The two pages in question are:

http://dev.betheshow.com/events/purple-people-painting-parlor/
http://dev.betheshow.com/events/jugglemania

I am using Ultimatum and Visual Composer, too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in `http://dev.betheshow.com/wp-content/plugins/appointment-booking/frontend/resources/js/bookly.js?ver=11.3` there are several javascript `scrollTo` commands. maybe one of them causes it. You should go step-by=step debugging to get the exact point, to find which one causes.